# soap service in microservice is it possible to build

Tags: web-services, soap, microservices, soa

good afternoon

I am reviewing the concepts of SOA and I have this question.

SOA-> COVERS in 2 technologies, SOAP(xml) AND REST(xml,json,txt,etc)

Microservices that is based on SOA, uses SOAP or is only based on REST?

obs: if it is clear that the microservice goes by the level of decoupling, independence and only specific tasks, but my question is if I can have microservices based on SOAP?

I have read a lot of documentation, I have that doubt.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microservices are more of a concept/software architecture style where you have independently and scalable services.
If your organisation/project requires soap protocol (which often happens in legacy projects when you want to switch from soa to microservces) you can also do microservices with it.